# HttpQueryServiceConfiguration error INVALID_HANDLE

Tags: http, winapi, https, smalltalk, httpserver

I am trying to get some configuration info for my Http server (implemented using `HTTP SERVER API` 2.0 from `Smalltalk`), by calling `HttpQueryServiceConfiguration`, and I am getting an `INVALID_HANDLE` (6) error.
I have reviewed all the documentation, and I think I am passing the correct parameters. No idea what could be wrong.

Here is how I am calling the api:

```
| length return |

info := HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_URLACL_SET external.
query := HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_URLACL_QUERY external.
key := HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_URLACL_KEY new.
key urlPrefix: 'http://localhost:50000/tp/'.
query KeyDesc: key.
length := ExternalLong external.
return := self dll
    HttpQueryServiceConfiguration: 0
    ConfigId: HttpServiceConfigUrlAclInfo
    pInputConfigInfo: query asParameter
    InputConfigInfoLength: query sizeInBytes
    pOutputConfigInfo: info asParameter
    OutputConfigInfoLength: info sizeInBytes
    pReturnLength: length asParameter
    pOverlapped: nil.
return = 0 ifFalse: [self osError: return]
```

Any idea will help,

Thanks!

Comment: **which** "Smalltalk"? Pharo, Squeak, VW, VA, Dolphin...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a note in the `HttpSetServiceConfiguration` function definition at the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). With this initialization, the function succeeds!!.

> Must call HttpInitialize/HttpTerminate
>   If you get error code 6 (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE) then be aware that you must >call HttpInitialize() with HTTP_INITIALIZE_CONFIG first.